# Javascript won't load on mobile. Works on desktop

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I made a simple calculator, works flawlessly on desktop. Then I tried it out on mobile. I thought it was just a problem with my click events not registering on the touchscreen, but I noticed something. One of the first things my JS does is an addClass, and it wasn't being added. So I wrote a couple alerts at the top and bottom of the JS document, and sure enough, they don't fire.

What puzzles me is why this entire thing works perfectly on desktop browsers, but not at all on mobile. Like the JS wasn't loaded at all. I get no errors in the console, and I've made sure my JS is ordered properly in my HTML document.

[The page can be viewed here](http://hootchmix.com).

Comment: What mobile might you mean, webkit browsers render javascript pretty well, like on Android

Comment: Safari and Chrome on iOS

Comment: are you using ios6 and POST requests by any chance? if yes go to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13707508/5447628)
also, if not, is javascript enabled, to check, follow instructions [here](http://activatejavascript.org/en/instructions/ios)

Comment: No, I'm not. iOS 9.2.1. I just checked to make sure Javascript is enabled for Safari. Does this site function on your device?

Comment: Yeah, it actually does, again, is javascript enabled on your device?

Comment: Yes it is. I followed the instructions provided in your link.

Comment: Another link http://stackoverflow.com/a/9549795/5447628

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aSum = newArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);`//'newArray.reduce' is worry at Safari.if you delete this code,will show alert beginning and finished.sorry,i don't know the method array.reduce..so can't give you solution.but if you need sum function of array,plz try `aSum=eval(newArray.join('+'));`

Comment: You're correct. I just discovered the iPhone debugger in Safari and saw that the => symbol was throwing an error. I changed my sum function to what you suggested, and it's fixed the problem. What a relief. Thanks for taking a look at this.

Comment: Nice.Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Works on Android Chrome. (Note 4)